# E: Version '18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu' for 'docker-ce-cli' was not found

Tags: docker

Trying to install docker from official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) on ubuntu and getting this error

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu docker-ce-cli=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu' for 'docker-ce-cli' was not found
```

Best part is that we just installed docker on another machine yesterday and it worked then. What gives?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Only way to get rid of the error was to not install docker-ce-cli

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu containerd.io
```

check version

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.06.1-ce
 API version:       1.38
 Go version:        go1.10.3
 Git commit:        e68fc7a
 Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:24:51 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:23:15 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu' for 'docker-ce' was not found
E: Unable to locate package containerd.io
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io' `
I tried this cmd but not able to install, does it worked for you?

Comment: Yes, have tried it. Able to install with `export VERSION=18.06.1-ce && curl -sSL get.docker.com | sh`

Answer (score 13):

To my knowledge the docker-ce-cli package was introduced in Docker CE 18.09. Before that docker-ce does not have that as a dependency. You can check that by for example look into the Packages file for Ubuntu Bionic: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/bionic/stable/binary-amd64/Packages

Cheers!

Comment: sorry but I did not understand this. are you saying that we should not install docker-ce-cli if we are going to use v18.06.1 of docker?

Comment: what does docker-ce-cli provide?

Comment: Just for clarification. Since 18.09 the client part of docker has been separated from docker-ce into docker-ce-cli. So install instructions for older releases than 18.09 was just to install docker-ce.

Answer (score 1):

run

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce-cli
```

and install one `docker-ce-cli` from that list